# The form tag is not display in a php loop

Tags: php, html, forms, while-loop

I am making a table that shows some data and I have it in a while where the data from the database is taken.
the problem is that I need a form tag for each of the tr to be able to take the data later, this works in all but not in the first field.
Code:

```
while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
    $user_name = $fila[0];
    //echo '<script>alert("'.$user_name.'");</script>';
    $last_name = $fila[1];
    $email1 = $fila[2];
    $id = $fila[3];
    echo '<form id="update_user'.$id.'" name="update_user'.$id.'" action="" method="post">';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="quit_click" id="nombre'.$id.'"><input id="innombre'.$id.'" name="innombre" type="text" value="'.$last_name.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td class="quit_click" id="user'.$id.'"><input id="inuser'.$id.'" name="inuser" type="text" value="'.$user_name.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td class="quit_click" id="email'.$id.'"><input id="inemail'.$id.'" name="inemail" type="text" value="'.$email1.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td class="quit_click" id="pass'.$id.'"><input id="inpass'.$id.'" name="inpass" type="text" value="********"/></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

In all fields it shows the form and the tr minus in the first one that only shows the content of the tr, does anyone know why?
If more code is needed, tell me

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please dont break the html structure, table tag should be followed with thead, tr and td so form shouldnot come in between. I cannot identify the issue without seeing the full code But Can you check by adding the table fully inside the form as given below

```
while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
    $user_name = $fila[0];
    $last_name = $fila[1];
    $email1 = $fila[2];
    $id = $fila[3];
    echo '<form id="update_user'.$id.'" name="update_user'.$id.'" action="" method="post">';
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="quit_click" id="nombre'.$id.'"><input id="innombre'.$id.'" name="innombre" type="text" value="'.$last_name.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td class="quit_click" id="user'.$id.'"><input id="inuser'.$id.'" name="inuser" type="text" value="'.$user_name.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td class="quit_click" id="email'.$id.'"><input id="inemail'.$id.'" name="inemail" type="text" value="'.$email1.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td class="quit_click" id="pass'.$id.'"><input id="inpass'.$id.'" name="inpass" type="text" value="********"/></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the error is that above (not seen in the code that I have put)
there was a form tag that gave conflict
Telling me about the form tags has made me think again about the structure and see the error, thanks again.

Comment: @RubenAmezcua the nesting of elements you had is wrong, no matter what happens in the parts we didn’t see - you can not nest a form into a table in such a place, the form either needs to be around the _complete_ table, or be contained in a single table _cell_. You can not place it where you did, around a table row.

Comment: @04FS Now it works, above I open a table and tbody and below (which is also not seen) I close the tbody and the table.
With this I get to have a different form for each tr of the table

Comment: _“With this I get to have a different form for each tr of the table”_ - Don’t rely on “it works”, based on your limited tests in a few or maybe even just one browser. This is **invalid HTML**, it has a high likelihood of leading you into trouble sooner or later. The error correction browsers apply to faulty HTML can lead to situations where this creates a different DOM than you are expecting, and make stuff like this fail completely in one way or another.

Comment: @RubenAmezcua  you can bring form  tag inside a td will be a better way, But without seeing the full code I cant give that.

Comment: @04FS and Ajith Thanks for the information and for trying to make my code better, tomorrow I will do more tests with several browsers, you will be informed.

Comment: Even “success” in all of the browser you’ll manage to test, will not change anything about this being _fundamentally wrong_.